# Use multiple mysql tables and display in one html table

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, html-table, el

I'm trying to add the number of orders into the last column in an html table by joining my `user2` table and `orders` table using a sql statement (I made the `userID` in "user" primary key and `userID` in `orders` foreign key) and using `setAttribute` in my Servlet class in order to use EL in my jsp file. This is the code I have right now in my Servlet class,

```
ps = conn
                .prepareStatement("select * FROM user2 WHERE lastname LIKE '%"
                        + searchReq + "%'");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            user = new User(rs.getInt("userID"), rs.getString("username"),
                    rs.getString("password"), rs.getString("firstname"),
                    rs.getString("lastname"), rs.getString("Email"),
                    rs.getInt("age"));
            listOfUsers.add(user);
```

and in my jsp:

```
<table border="1" class="search-table">

    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Orders</td>


    </tr>

    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.lou}" var="current">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${current.id}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${current.username}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${current.password}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${current.firstname}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${current.lastname}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${current.email}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${current.age}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${orders}" /></td>


        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

My orders table has userID, orderID, Shipping, and item as columns, and I count the number of orders by using orderID per userID.

I am just unsure how to get the number of orders to go into each row in my html table, since when I used a subquery in the "select * FROM user2...etc" statement it returns more than one row (as it should) but I'm not sure how to handle the multiple rows. Or is there a different way to handle this?

Comment: You have to JOIN those two tables together into one somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to **learn SQL**.

To get a count of orders as an extra column of your query result, use a subselect, e.g.

```sql
SELECT userID
     , username
     , password
     , firstname
     , lastname
     , Email
     , age
     , ( SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM orders o
          WHERE o.userID = u.userID
       ) AS orders
  FROM user2 u
 WHERE lastname LIKE ?
```

That SQL also uses a parameter marker (`?`), and you specify the value of the marker by calling `setString()` of a `PreparedStatement`.

You do **NOT** do it using string concatenation, unless you want hackers to use [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) to steal your data and/or delete you tables.

Comment: I'm just having trouble getting it into the html table.

Answer (score 0):

just in case anyone wants to know what I did with the help I received above, (I'm a beginner so it's definitely not the best answer or anything, it just works for what I was trying to do)

```
ps = conn
                .prepareStatement("SELECT userID, username, password, firstname, lastname, email, age, ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders o WHERE o.userID = u.userID) AS orders FROM user2 u WHERE lastname LIKE ? ");
        ps.setString(1, "%" + searchReq + "%");

        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            user = new User(rs.getInt("userID"), rs.getString("username"),
                    rs.getString("password"), rs.getString("firstname"),
                    rs.getString("lastname"), rs.getString("Email"),
                    rs.getInt("age"));

            listOfUsers.add(user);

            order = rs.getInt("orders");
            user.setOrders(order);
```

and then near the end of my doPost method `request.setAttribute("orders", order);`

in my jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.lou}" var="current">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${current.id}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${current.username}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${current.password}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${current.firstname}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${current.lastname}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${current.email}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${current.age}" /></td>
            <td><c:out value="${current.orders}" /></td>


        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

and made the setter and getter for orders in the User class.